# Paste only text/plain in contenteditable div whitch was add with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

**Hello**

I have a code

**html**

```
<div style="color:red">Some <em>rich</em> <span style="font-size:2em">HTML</span></div>
<div class='myDiv' contenteditable></div>
<button class="commButtonS">OPEN</button>
```

**css**

```
div[contenteditable] {
    height: 100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.commButtonS', function(){
        $('.commButtonS').after("<div class='myDiv' contenteditable></div>");
    }); 
    document.querySelector(".myDiv").addEventListener("paste", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HBEzc/478/

It allow past only text/plain in contenteditable div.

But it dosen't work with contenteditable div whitch was add with js.

How to make the code work ?

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting the myDiv when the page loads, so the event is only applied to the first div. you need to use event delegation instead. You code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.commButtonS', function(){
        $('.commButtonS').after("<div class='myDiv' contenteditable></div>");
    }); 
    $(document).on("paste", ".myDiv", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
    }); });
```